# Executing windll.version.GetFileVersionInfoSizeA() fails in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ctypes, python-3.8

I am trying to execute `windll.version.GetFileVersionInfoSizeA()` in python `ctypes`. I am executing the below code:

```
_GetFileVersionInfoSizeA = ctypes.windll.version.GetFileVersionInfoSizeA
_GetFileVersionInfoSizeA.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_void_p]
_GetFileVersionInfoSizeA.restype = ctypes.c_uint32
_GetFileVersionInfoSizeA.errcheck = RaiseIfZero # RaiseIfZero is a function to raise error
# lptstrFilename is the file path
dwLen = _GetFileVersionInfoSizeA(lptstrFilename, None)
```

This code works perfectly in python 2, but it's not working in python 3.8. It gives the following error:

```
argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

According to [msdn doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winver/nf-winver-getfileversioninfosizea) for `GetFileVersionInfoSizeA`, the second argument should be:

> "A pointer to a variable that the function sets to zero."

I tried the following code, but it gives the same error as before.

```
dwLen = _GetFileVersionInfoSizeA(lptstrFilename, LPVOID)
```

I am not sure what am I missing.
Note - This is my first time using `ctypes`.

Answer (score 1):

In **python2** two types could be used to represent strings. **strings** and **Unicode strings.** Hence `c_char_p` ctypes type is used to represent the ***python2 string type*** and `c_wchar_p` ctypes type is used to represent the ***python2 unicode string type***.

But in **python3 there is only one string type**. Hence `c_wchar_p` ctypes type is used to represent the python3 `string` type and `c_char_p` ctypes type is used to represent the python3 `bytes` type.

You can find the Fundamental data types in [`python 2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types) and [`python 3`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types) documentation.

So you could do

```
dwLen = _GetFileVersionInfoSizeA(your_file_name.encode(), None)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 strings are Unicode by default.  Even in Python 2 its best to use Unicode strings, and therefore the W versions of Windows APIs, which are natively Unicode.  So to call that API strictly according to documentation:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> from ctypes import wintypes as w
>>> dll = WinDLL('api-ms-win-core-version-l1-1-0')
>>> GetFileVersionInfoSize = dll.GetFileVersionInfoSizeW
>>> GetFileVersionInfoSize.argtypes = w.LPCWSTR,w.LPDWORD
>>> GetFileVersionInfoSize.restype = w.DWORD
>>> GetFileVersionInfoSize('test.exe',byref(w.DWORD())) # create a temporary DWORD passed by reference.
2316
```

Note that the second parameter is not documented to accept *nullptr*(a.k.a `None` in Python) so it should be a valid reference.

To call the ANSI(A) version of the function pass a byte string encoded correctly in the default ANSI encoding e.g. `'test.exe'.encode('ansi')`, but note that non-ASCII filenames will cause trouble that is mitigated by using the Unicode(W) version.